# Using the resolution method in logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Using the resolution method in logic, having these clauses

$$\{ \neg M \vee S, \neg S \vee T, \neg W \vee T, W \vee M, \neg T, \neg T \vee S \}$$

is it possible to reach the contradiction directly by voiding $\neg S \vee T$ with $\neg T \vee S$?

Cheers.

Comment: What do you mean with 'voiding'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Applying resolution to $\neg S\lor T$ and $\neg T\lor S$ produces either $\neg S \lor S$ or $T\lor \neg T$ -- and neither of these are contradictions. On the contrary they are *tautologies*.

You can't annihilate more than one pair of literals in a single resolution step.